# While fetching values from database the single quotes shows ? icon in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am making a simple blog model in php for now i have added this data directly in data from phpmy admin this is the dummy data

```
Post-ironic mumblecore authentic, stumptown try-hard chambray sartorial 
McSweeney’s VHS put a bird on it. Pitchfork lomo meggings, meh whatever cred 
beard four loko hella. Flannel swag normcore, leggings 3 wolf moon meditation 
Marfa hella fingerstache Thundercats mustache. Lo-fi typewriter Shoreditch, 
Odd Future fingerstache iPhone retro McSweeney’s four loko Kickstarter hoodie
```

The above text has `'` single quotes values in it now the problem is when the vales are being parsed in php and then displayed in HTML format it shows � instead of single quote.

What might be the problem?

This is the output i am geeting in html format

```
Post-ironic mumblecore authentic, stumptown try-hard chambray sartorial 
McSweeney�s VHS put a bird on it. Pitchfork lomo meggings, meh whatever 
cred beard four loko hella. Flannel swag normcore, leggings 3 wolf moon 
meditation Marfa hella fingerstache Thundercats mustache. Lo-fi typewriter 
Shoreditch, Odd Future fingerstache iPhone retro McSweeney�s four loko 
Kickstarter hoodie
```

I am using the normal php code to display the data like this `<?php echo $value['post_content']; ?>` i have even tried the `htmlspecialchars_decode` function in PHP but doesn't work well

I am using OOP PHP technique and this is the code i am using

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$connection = $this->establish_connection();
$data = $connection->query($query);
$connection->close();
```

Comment: You should include a code snippet showing the relevant PHP and HTML, including where you're initializing this dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Unicode problem .

The original text is encoded with different Unicode not that you use to display (`utf8`) so  , try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$connection = $this->establish_connection();
$connection->set_charset("utf8"); 
$data = $connection->query($query);
$connection->close();
```

Comment: the first option says cannot modify headers as they are already sent and the 2nd one didnt work

Comment: u save your page as utf8 , so try the second one

Comment: this is my head `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: ok let me show you , your original text interrupting with utf8 and that why i said make it back to original

Comment: i am sure your original text not in utf8

Comment: yes correct how to save it in database in UTF8 format ?

Comment: for db you should use ALTER db to change Collation but right now just put this before select query ,  $yourconnection->set_charset("utf8");

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your commas are standard single quote characters. Converting them to their numerical representation and comparing it to a standard single quote makes this clear.

Try the following: Either replacing all of those commas with standard single quotes, or convert your existing commas into their corresponding HTML entities or unicode representation. If you convert them, then test them across different browsers to ensure cross-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a meta encoding inside the head tags of your html matching the encoding of the data in your db, eg:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

It's important to match the encoding both in your files and your database. You can use the tool **save with encoding** in most text editors and set the encoding of the table fields in your database.

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav and is it the same encoding of your db and the php file that manages the insert in db? You need to set the charset that matches your encoding, or save with the encoding that matches your charset.